# Mapping array into array of tuples using LoDash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I've got an array such as:

```
var foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

and I would like to map it to:

```
var bar = [[1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [4,5], [5,1]];
```

I do not need to handle scenarios where the length of `foo` is 0 or 1.

My naive approach is:

```js
var foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var bar = _.map(foo, function(value, index) {
  return index < foo.length - 1 ? [value, foo[index + 1]] : [value, foo[0]];
});

console.log(bar);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

I'm wondering if there's a more clear way to express this mapping.

Comment: This question is more suited for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). You already solved the problem but you are seeking directions to improve.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Please note that Code Review requires real code; questions containing placeholders like `foo` would be off-topic there.

Comment: @200_success Yes you're right, I'm personally not a user of Code Review, so my experience is limited with it, but OP could take the **real function** he's using and it would work. It would even be better since maybe there's a better solution for his scenario than grouping the array.

Comment: @EmileBergeron there are currently [685 unanswered 'javascript' questions on CR](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript?sort=unanswered&pageSize=50) - surely one of them is waiting for *your* review! ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug I actually read the rules this week and was thinking in doing some reviews.

Comment: http://ramdajs.com/docs/#aperture gets you close. Just need to use `[...foo, foo[0]]` as your input. Could check their source for the implementation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using plain simple lodash. First drop the first element from the array, append it, and then zip it with the original array:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5]
var b = _.zip(a, _.concat(_.drop(a), a[0]))
```

The result:

```
console.log(b)
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 1]]
```

Answer (score 3):

> [`_.nth`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#nth)
>
> Gets the element at index `n` of array. If `n` is negative, the nth element from the end is returned.

just get sibling in reverse order

```
var bar = _.map(foo, function(val, index) {
    return [val, _.nth(foo, (index + 1) - foo.length)];
});
```